# Start a Hadoop Map Reduce Job on a remote cluster in Eclipse with the run dialog (F11)

Tags: eclipse, hadoop, spring-data, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

Is it possible to start a Map Reduce job on a remote cluster with the Eclipse *Run Dialog* (F11)?

Currently I have to run it with the *External Tool Chain Dialog* and Maven.

**Note:** To execute it on a local cluster is no big deal with the *Run Dialog*. But for a remote connection it's mandatory to have a compiled JAR. Otherwise you get a `ClassNotFoundException` (also if `Jar-By-Class` is set)

Our current Setup is:

- Spring-Data-Hadoop 1.0.0
- STS - Springsource Toolsuite
- Maven
- CDH4

This we set on our `applicationContext.xml` (this is what you specify in the *-site.xml on a vanilla hadoop)

```
 <hdp:configuration id="hadoopConfiguration">
    fs.defaultFS=hdfs://carolin.ixcloud.net:8020
    mapred.job.tracker=michaela.ixcloud.net:8021
</hdp:configuration>
```

Is there a way to tell Eclipse it should build a JAR when the *Run Dialog* is executed.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if it builds a new jar (may be you must extract a jar to a folder), adding "Run Configurations->Classpath" your jar clears the problem "ClassNotFoundException".

Comment: Hi Alpher, it seems that eclipse is not building a jar. I guess it just put the all the compiled classes into the classpath. I the Project as you mentioned. Without success :(

Comment: Then, before you run your program, you must extract the jar in a folder in your eclipse project using right click and "export->jar"

Comment: ok, but that's more or less what i am during currently with the external Tool Chain and maven. This is very unhandy because you have to do this for every change you like to test :(